# No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Twitter] found for dependency

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-social

In my Spring Boot application I'm trying to implement Twitter oAuth support.
Following this example http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-twitter/ I have successfully added Twitter access to my application, so now I have:

HomeController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    private Twitter twitter;

    private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;      

    @Inject
    public HelloController(Twitter twitter, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        this.twitter = twitter;
        this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloTwitter(Model model) {
        if (connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Twitter.class) == null) {
            return "redirect:/connect/twitter";
        }

        TwitterProfile userProfile = twitter.userOperations().getUserProfile();

        model.addAttribute(userProfile);
        CursoredList<TwitterProfile> friends = twitter.friendOperations().getFriends();
        model.addAttribute("friends", friends);
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

Application class:

```
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties") })
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

So far everything works fine. I can start Application without any issues.

Also, I have a lot of integration tests, for example:

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@IntegrationTest("server.port: 0")
public class SearchControllerTest {

    @Value("${local.server.port}")
    protected int port;

    @Test
    public void testSearchResultsWithDefaultPageAndSize() {
        // @formatter:off
        given()
            .when()
                .get(format("http://localhost:%d/api/v1.0/search/%s", port, "RDBMa mosyl"))
            .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .body("totalCount", equalTo(4))
                .body("entries.size", equalTo(4));
        // @formatter:on
    }
....
}
```

Now, after adding of Twitter social functionality, all my tests failed with following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.social.twitter.api.Twitter] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Why does this work with Application and fails with tests ? What is wrong with my tests configuration ?

Comment: I would recommend starting by removing `@PropertySources` and `@ComponentScan` from your application class. It's annotated as `@SpringBootApplication`, so those just confuse things.

Comment: Also, do you have a `src/main/resources/application.properties` or `config/application.properties`, which defines `spring.social.twitter.appId` and `spring.social.twitter.appSecret`?

Comment: Yeah.. this is a reason ! I got it after your first comment about application.properties.. I forgot to add spring.social.twitter.* properties to my src/TEST/resources/application.properties . Thank you so much !

Comment: I was getting the same exception, but in my case it was because I didn't include the @WebAppConfiguration annotation. It seems that Spring boot does not instantiate Spring Social classes in the absence of a WebApplicationContext, which I don't get as someone could be interested in cosuming twitter from a command line app and still don't want to manually configure a TwitterTemplate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is you don't have a src/main/resources/application.properties or config/application.properties, which defines `spring.social.twitter.appId` and `spring.social.twitter.appSecret`.